# How to pass GCLID from page to page

Tags: analytics, google-ads-api

We have a site that gets traffic from adwords. When adwords link clicked landing page of the site have **gclid=xxxx**  extra parameter to track stats.

After landing page, if user navigates away from that page (still staying in the site) gclid parameter are not added to following page URLs.

I checked some other sites' adwords campaigns and saw that gclid remains in the URL no mater how many pages navigated.

Is this a **feature** by adwords or do I need to pass gclid parameter **manually**  from page to page?

If I need to pass manually, is there a way to accomplish this with javascript? Because it is very hard to edit the CMS framework to add the parameter for all the links.

Note: Our advertisement company tells they are observing too many "direct/none" source in analytics and  claims that this is because of the gclid parameter not passing through pages. Do you think is this the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post contains a number of questions:

> Is this a feature by adwords

No, Adwords offers no such feature.

> If I need to pass manually, is there a way to accomplish this with javascript?

Yes, you could check for the existence of a `gclid` parameter in the document's URL and dynamically append it to any internal links on the page. But that's not required (see below).

> ... too many "direct/none" source ... because of the gclid parameter not passing through pages. Do you think is this the case

No, that's not the case. The linking between Adwords and Analytics depends on the `gclid` parameter being present on the **initial hit** of a session, where the Analytics script will pick it up and associate it with that user. Going forward, any direct hit from the same user will still be attributed to Adwords (up until the campaign timeout is reached). Maybe this [Google Analytics documentation page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762) will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the GCLID value in Session Storage or Cookies.
Decode the GCLID value and keep it as a hidden value in any of the forms on your website.